# Is there a way to browse the Rift store without activating the game?

Tags: rift

I know that in Rift's main website they have a link which displays options for purchasing credits, patron, and a few other features. Inside of the game however the Rift store displays a greater amount of different items that you can purchase such as mounts, extra bag slots, extra crafting profession slots, etc.

Is there any way other than being inside of the game to view the store and see what the prices for things like what I mentioned above are?

Answer (score 1):

**No, there isn't.**

Although the RIFT Store is an excellent resource, it can only be accessed from in-game.